# My account is banned

Tags: support, ban

I`m no able to ask questions on stackoverflow. Can I be unbanned? Else can I know quantifiable step to do to release the ban?

Comment: For starters, stop using the accent as apostrophe and start reading error messages.

Answer (score 2):

You've asked 6 questions, 4 of which have been deleted.

What you need to do [is covered here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers).

I'm going to try to personalize it a little bit, just because you probably can't see the deleted questions in your profile.

You have four deleted questions:

- [Flash developer vs RIA developer vs Interactive Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251360/flash-developer-vs-ria-developer-vs-interactive-developer)
- [Max folders I can store inside a folder in a linux server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193923/max-folders-i-can-store-inside-a-folder-in-a-linux-server)
- [php script to download files from a repeating node of an xml feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9174582/php-script-to-download-files-from-a-repeating-node-of-an-xml-feed)
- [I need to filter an rss feed using php [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7823476/i-need-to-filter-an-rss-feed-using-php)

I'm not sure why the duplicate was deleted; since we have guidance to keep those around.  The one question you should fix up are the the "PHP script to download files".

In your case, it seems like the only thing that's going to help you is to improve your existing questions and to give good answers.  Most of your deleted questions can't be helped.

Comment: I deleted the questions because they got negative votes, that`s what I thought is the best thing to do to release the ban.

Comment: @MahmoudBadri No, deleted posts count towards a post ban.  The only thing you can do to get out of a ban is to improve your questions and hopefully the community will upvote them.

Comment: can I undelete my questions then?

Comment: @MahmoudBadri You can undelete any that you deleted.

Comment: ok, undeleted all my quesstions, hopefully one day I`ll see my acount unbanned :) thnx

Comment: @MahmoudBadri It's all on the work you do.  If you improve your questions and post good answers, you could be unbanned.

Comment: I`m curious about something, can I edit and old down voted question and instead of improving it, asking a new totally different question in its place?

Comment: @MahmoudBadri: No, that's not allowed.