# Does deleting your own question when it has 0 or more reputation and zero answers hurt you?

Tags: discussion

If, for some reason, I wanted to delete my question after I posted it, with the following info in mind, would my account be hurt in any way?

- It has 0 or more reputation attached to it
- It has no flags
- It has no answers

Would it be as if I never posted it?

Comment: I wouldn't say its side-effect free.  The site keeps a permanent record of everything that happens.  But, the same can be said of almost everywhere on the Internet.

Comment: I mean, would my account be harmed? I don't care if an admin can look at it 10 years from now.

Comment: description of a side-effect  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers

Comment: [This comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184087/my-account-is-banned/184095#comment562321_184095) may be worth a read.

Answer (score 7):

The exact rules are not publicized and subject to change without notice. As a rule of thumb, if...

- No one else has put significant effort into your question, or
- It is more than 30 days old

...then you can delete it without penalty, [provided the system allows it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that).

If the question has been answered or critiqued, you're better off doing what you can to improve it first. This isn't *always* possible, but folks who make a *habit* of posting poor questions and then deleting them will tend to find themselves in trouble.

Comment: I look at the OP of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17841291/how-to-debug-php-that-is-executed-by-command-line-by-another-program-that-has-no) (10k only). He says he deletes his questions because he doesn't want his "sekretz" shared with Google and n00bs (Hippocrate)

Comment: This is not uncommon. Authors delete more questions than any other single group.

Answer (score 5):

The algorithm of the question ban is secret. Your question falls under that category. In other words

> The developers could tell you but then they'd have to kill you.

And you should always think twice before asking to make sure only good questions being asked on the network.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just leave it how it is...it could potentially earn you a nice shiny badge:  Tumbleweed (bronze)

> Asked a question with no votes, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week